# SSH login without password with kerberos

Tags: ssh, authentication, kerberos

I try to login onto a server which only supports login with kerberos authentication. Here's what I try:

```
kinit user@FOO.ORG
aklog -c foo.org
ssh server
```

But then I'm asked again for a password.

Here's what I have in my `~/.ssh/config` for the entry `server` (my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is empty):

```
Host server
    HostName someserver.foo.org
    User user
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

According to colleagues, this (or something similar) is working for them. I can log onto other machines with kerberos tokens just fine. I assume it has something to do with my `/etc/krb5.conf`, but I do not know what to look for. I tried copying the `/etc/krb5.conf` from the server to my working station, but without success.

Here's part of the output if I run `ssh -vvv server`:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
```

How can I login with my local kerberos token? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just create a key and put the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server?  `man ssh-keygen`

Comment: @MikeA The server accepts only connections with a valid kerberos token.

Comment: Try setting `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file and retry. Also look at `PreferredAuthentications` setting and make sure you have `gssapi-with-mic` first

Comment: @VenkatC I tried both of these before, no success.

Comment: From your ssh debug above, I do not see it's trying to use kerberos credentials anywhere. would you post ssh output with GSSAPIAuthentication, GSSAPIKeyExchange both set to yes ? also post klist output before ssh

Comment: @VenkatC Sorry, I somehow missed your second comment. I've updated the question now by adding `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` to the `~/.ssh/config` and the important part of the `ssh -vvv` command.

Comment: The error "server not found in kerberos database" generally means that the host to which you're trying to connect does not have a valid `/etc/krb5.keytab` file.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. So do I understand correctly it's a problem on the server? I wonder why other people then can connect though.

Comment: Actually, I'm confused now.  Are you saying that your colleagues can log into the *same* server successfully?  *And* you are able to successfully log into other servers using your Kerberos ticket?  If you could update your question to be explicit about which situations are working (or not), that might help.

Comment: make sure DNS resolves properly for server `someserver.foo.org` - both forward and reverse lookup. This is important for kerberos functionality. Also clarify, if other users could log on to same server from the same client you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add the server to the kerberos data base aka KDC by creating a principal for the machine itself.

If you are running Windows Active Directory with a KDC you can use the ktpass.exe to add the host to the KDC.

if you are running Windows or Linux Kerberos KDC you can use the ktutil command in a linux shell to at the principal to the kerberos database.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that NTPD service has gone down, Atleast in my case, when checked the status , service failed with logs having PANIC_STOP, try below steps-

1. `systemctl stop ntpd`
2. `systemctl status ntpd`
3. Please take note of one of the servers in `/etc/ntpd.conf`
4. `ntpdate <ABOVE SERVER>`
5. `systemctl start ntpd`

Comment: Some of the steps are not necessary, and it would make sense to first verify whether the time is actually wrong.